# Listbox jumps to top when resuming scroll from last position

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

(Windows Phone 8.1) In my app, I have a MainPage with a listbox. NavigationCacheMode is set to required to preserve the state when navigating back to the same page.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    // cache page
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
}
```

So when I go to another page and come back to my MainPage everthing looks the same as I left it. The Listbox is also in the corrent position. But whenever I touch it, it will jump to the top before it scrolls...

How can I make it so that it resumes scrolling before going to the top first?

EDIT: solved

Seems like Listbox is bugged in WP8.1, use ListView instead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and figured out that it's primarily the chosen ItemsPanelTemplate which causes the Bug.

When using a ListView, the standard ItemsPanelTemplate is ItemsStackPanel, which works fine. If you change that to VirtualizingStackPanel (standard for ListBox) the bug appears. But only on Windows Phone, for Windows it works like expected.

So I assume that, when you like to use ListBox instead of ListView, you have to use ItemStackPanel as ItemsPanelTemplate to preserve the scroll position via NavigationCacheMode.

Comment: I'm also getting this bug. Is there any way to use a virtualized panel, but manually restore scroll position?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but unfortunately it's quite some effort needed. First you have to scan the VisualTree to find the ScrollViewer (end of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579(v=vs.110).aspx) which only works after rendering of list is finished. After you've got the ScrollViewer you can extract horizontal/vertical offset and save it. When returning to that page, you have to scan the VisualTree again, after you got the ScrollViewer and the list content is rendered you can scroll to your saved position (ScrollViewer.ChangeView). I found no nice way to await rendering so far :/

Comment: This solution works as long as long as the NavigationCacheMode is set to Disabled. Of course, now that it's disabled you have to manually track any UI properties you want to persist. I've not figured out a way to use this technique with caching, because the ListView jumps not on load, but when you touch it again to scroll.